# Find which transaction is changing IsolationLevel

Tags: sql-server, database, isolation-level, database-deadlocks

My application is calling multiple SPs it seems like between these calls the isolation level is being changed to Serializable. I have went through the code and we are not setting the isolation level anywhere. Is it possible to know if SQL connection pool is setting this level?

I am using MS SQL 2008 R2.

When I run SQL profiler, I see that the isolation has changed. The SP called is not changing it. Is it that since the isolation level is not specified, SQL connection pool is deciding which level to use and not setting it back?

```
Audit Login -- network protocol: LPC
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort on
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level serializable
```

Comment: Do you happen to be using Entity Framework in your app? I've run into issues where it used Serializable as the default and it was surprising (to me at least).

Comment: We are using SqlCommand, Ben.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reused pooled connections do not change the transaction isolation level.

Perhaps you are using `TransactionScope`. [The default isolation level with TransactionScope is serializable](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2010/06/03/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful/) unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Dan. In our code, we are using using   (var trans = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)) . Looks like this might be the culprit